# Is " Let me know your opinion" correct?

Tags: phrases

What are the possible structures that follow the phrase: let somebody know. For example, is "Let me know your opinion" correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs has the entry:

> let someone know (about something) to tell someone something; to
>   inform someone of something.
>
> Please let me know about it soon. Will you be coming to the picnic?
>   Please let me know.

There are various common structures:

Please let me know about it. / Please let me know.

Let me know what you think. // Let me know what/how you feel about it. // Let me know if you are coming.

Let me know your name/favourite song // answer // thoughts/opinion/heart/preference/take on this matter/...  This apparently ditransitive construction is really a shortening of the related wh-clause 'Let me know what your name is' etc.